# Java code finds Armstrong number upto 3 digit numbers but fails on 4 digit onwards

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, while-loop

I just started learning java 2 days ago and tried doing an assignment to find if the three digit number was an Armstrong number or not. This code works upto 3 digit numbers and after that it fails to work on 4 digit Armstrong numbers like 1634, 8208 etc..

```
public class project1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int number = 9474, originalNumber, remainder, result = 0;

    originalNumber = number;

    while (originalNumber != 0)
    {
        remainder = originalNumber % 10;
        result += Math.pow(remainder, 3);
        originalNumber /= 10;
    }

    if(result == number)
        System.out.println(number + " is an Armstrong number.");
    else
        System.out.println(number + " is not an Armstrong number.");
}
}
```

Comment: It looks like you are determining Armstrong numbers, a.k.a. [Narcissistic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcissistic_number).  That link has Java code to determine them.  Get the number of digits first, then get the sum of digits raised to that power.  You're hard-coding an exponent of 3.

Comment: Looks like i had failed to understand what an armstrong number is . 4 digits number should have power 4  and 5 digits the power used should be 5 and so on... Thank u for the clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution just support 3 digit numbers. If you want to change it for numbers with any digits should first count number of digits:

```
int numberOfDigits = 0;
while (originalNumber != 0) {
     numberOfDigits++;
     originalNumber /= 10;
}
```

And then just a minor changes in your code for power of `Math.pow` method as:

```
result += Math.pow(remainder, numberOfDigits);
```

The  complete solution is:

```
class project1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int number = 9474, originalNumber, remainder, result = 0;

        originalNumber = number;

        int numberOfDigits = 0;
        while (originalNumber != 0) {
            numberOfDigits++;
            originalNumber /= 10;
        }

        originalNumber = number;

        while (originalNumber != 0) {
            remainder = originalNumber % 10;
            result += Math.pow(remainder, numberOfDigits);
            originalNumber /= 10;
        }

        if (result == number)
            System.out.println(number + " is an Armstrong number.");
        else
            System.out.println(number + " is not an Armstrong number.");
    }
}
```

Comment: This was the solution i was looking for. thanx for helping

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ArmstrongNumberDemo
{
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  int num = 9474, realNumber, remainder, output = 0, a = 0;
  realNumber = num;
  for(;realNumber != 0; realNumber /= 10, ++a);
  realNumber = num;
  for(;realNumber != 0; realNumber /= 10){
     remainder = realNumber % 10;
     output += Math.pow(remainder, a);
  }
  if(output == num){
     System.out.println(num + " is an Armstrong number.");
  }
  else{
     System.out.println(num + " is not an Armstrong number.");
  }
  }
 }
```

Comment: Can you please explain the code to help the people that find this answer to understand. (Use the edit button to do so)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).